# Update an entity in ef core w/o querying it specifying the alternate key?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to update an entity (without requesting it) by just specifying the alternateKey. Is this possible?

```
using (var db = GetContext())
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    // [...]

    var status = new ImportStatus();
    status.ID = 201;  // don't know the real PK. With PK it works!
    status.Symbol = symbol; // this is the alternateKey
    status.DateLastImport = DateTime.Now;

    db.Attach(status);
    db.Entry(status).Property("DateLastImport").IsModified = true;

    await db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *DbContext.Entry()* to explicitly set the state and it should work:

```
using (var db = GetContext())
using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    // [...]

    var status = new ImportStatus();

    status.Symbol = symbol;
    status.DateLastImport = DateTime.Now;

     //Explicitly setting the State should be all you need to do
    context.Entry(status).State = EntityState.Modified;

    await db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

**EDIT:**

There is a breaking change in EF Core 3.0, the solution proposed here won't work: if PK is unset the entity will be considered Added even though you explicitly set the persistent state. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#dc)

Comment: Now i get: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'ID' on entity type 'ImportStatus' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Modified'. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.` Which also looks like its trying to insert the record.

Comment: @Viper I see the problem, more info in the link posted here, maybe you can apply the work around they suggest if this is a legacy app you are upgrading

Comment: good catch. Thanks for your further investigating. Sadly i can't use the workaround in my application. For now i will select the entity and update it then. Its just annoying and not a problem :D